# How to create Cron job for every two hours starting from time from 6am to 6pm PST ? Any possibility of excluding weekends?

Tags: cron, databricks, cron-task, kubernetes-cronjob

I have to create a Cron job every two hours, starting from time 6 am PST to 6 pm PST. Also any possibility of excluding weekends?

It will be used in databricks.

Answer (score 3):

```
0 0 6-18/2 ? * MON-FRI
```

It worked very fine,people can use for their work